# Stack layout in D3 version 4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I'm trying to convert D3v3 stacked bar in https://codepen.io/goodforenergy/pen/PNPxxv?editors=0010 to D3v4 but I'm having trouble getting the call to `stack()` work correctly.

In the example above, the call to `d3.layout.stack()(dataset)` adds a `y0` property to the dataset's objects:

> `dataset` before the call: `{y=3, x="Test"}`
>
> `dataset` after the call: `{y=3, x="Test", y0=0}`

However in D3v4, when calling `d3.stack()(dataset);`, no such magic happens. So subsequently, `y0` is `undefined`.

What is missing here to add the `y0` values? A stacked bar is no good if the bars are not stacked on top but in front of each other...

Answer (score 1):

v4 stack creates an array of values that correspond to y0, y1

d[0] = y0
d[1] = y1

and then the input data is in d.values.

https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#stack